# TypeError when trying to save xarray to netcdf

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I would appreciate any help on this please. I have an xarray which was created from a pandas dataframe using the .to_xarray() method and has the following form:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 556, lon: 1438, time: 96)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2005-01-01 2006-01-01 ... 2100-01-01
  * lat      (lat) float64 -55.38 -55.12 -54.88 -54.62 ... 82.88 83.12 83.38
  * lon      (lon) float64 -69.88 -69.62 -69.38 -69.12 ... -26.12 -24.38 -24.12
Data variables:
    1.0      (lat, lon, time) float32 nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
    2.0      (lat, lon, time) float32 nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
    3.0      (lat, lon, time) float32 nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
    4.0      (lat, lon, time) float32 nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
    5.0      (lat, lon, time) float32 nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
    6.0      (lat, lon, time) float32 nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
    7.0      (lat, lon, time) float32 nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
```

When I try to save it using .to_netcdf() I get the following error:

```
TypeError: DataArray.name or Dataset key must be either a string or None for serialization to netCDF files
```

I tried changing the name of the variables by ds_land[1.0].name = 'class_1' etc, but that produces the same error as well. Any ideas please?

Comment: Can you provide a minimum working example to reproduce the error, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`rename()`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.rename.html) to rename your variable to a string before serializing, rather than setting the `name` attribute on your DataArray. This is because [variables names in netCDF must be strings](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/file_format_specifications.html).

```py
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.Dataset()
ds[1.0] = xr.DataArray([1, 2, 3])

ds[1.0].attrs['name'] = 'class_1'
ds.to_netcdf('testing.nc') # this fails, as you have seen

ds = ds.rename({1.0: 'class_1'})
ds.to_netcdf('testing2.nc') # this works
```

So renaming your variable to `'1.0'` would also do the trick:

```py
ds = xr.Dataset()
ds[1.0] = xr.DataArray([1, 2, 3])
ds = ds.rename({1.0: '1.0'})
ds.to_netcdf('testing3.nc') # this also works
```

As an aside, given how you have named your variables, it seems like they might be better off as another dimension, so you have a single new variable dimensioned by `lat`, `lon`, `time`, `<new dim with levels 1..7>`.