# TypeError when trying to save xarray WRF cross section to netcdf

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to save the xarray DataArray below as netcdf, but I get error "ValueError: unable to infer dtype on variable 'xy_loc'; xarray cannot serialize arbitrary Python objects". The data is a cross section produced using vertcross from the wrf package. I have resolved an earlier issue ("invalid value for attr") by removing the problem attributes as suggested here ([TypeError when trying to save xarray to netcdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61775642/typeerror-when-trying-to-save-xarray-to-netcdf)), but I do not understand what exactly about the xy_loc coordinate is a problem?

```
xarray.DataArray 'QVAPOR_cross' (XTIME: 2, vertical: 59, cross_line_idx: 239)
array([[[          nan,           nan,           nan, ...,
                   nan,           nan,           nan],
        [5.2142618e-03, 5.4577263e-03, 5.6551830e-03, ...,
         1.1576526e-02, 1.1481316e-02, 1.2421611e-02],
        [4.7921482e-03, 4.8334384e-03, 4.8439419e-03, ...,
         5.1765046e-03, 5.3730649e-03, 5.0648679e-03],
        ...,
        [3.1173588e-06, 3.1196325e-06, 3.1220573e-06, ...,
         1.7669336e-06, 1.8619023e-06, 1.9090951e-06],
        [3.2124219e-06, 3.2157229e-06, 3.2187045e-06, ...,
         1.9386096e-06, 1.9239062e-06, 1.8803454e-06],
        [          nan,           nan,           nan, ...,
         2.2164093e-06, 2.1845497e-06, 2.1732367e-06]],

       [[          nan,           nan,           nan, ...,
                   nan,           nan,           nan],
        [5.0503691e-03, 5.2436758e-03, 5.4539447e-03, ...,
         1.2035056e-02, 1.1335670e-02, 1.2419974e-02],
        [4.7799554e-03, 4.7886986e-03, 4.7935634e-03, ...,
         5.3098863e-03, 5.4153400e-03, 5.0202534e-03],
        ...,
        [3.1646039e-06, 3.1631198e-06, 3.1618749e-06, ...,
         1.8017681e-06, 1.8647409e-06, 1.8782921e-06],
        [3.2718322e-06, 3.2725636e-06, 3.2733096e-06, ...,
         1.8897241e-06, 1.8277435e-06, 1.7775615e-06],
        [          nan,           nan,           nan, ...,
         2.1244794e-06, 2.1224316e-06, 2.1411674e-06]]], dtype=float32)

Coordinates:
XTIME    (XTIME)          float64  720.0 780.0
Time     ()               object   None
xy_loc   (cross_line_idx) object   CoordPair(x=162.0, y=246.0, lat=...
vertical (vertical)       float32  970.83813 964.3068 ... 10.491312

Attributes:
FieldType : 104
description : Water vapor mixing ratio
units : kg kg-1
stagger :
coordinates : XLONG XLAT XTIME
projection : LambertConformal(stand_lon=-78.0, moad_cen_lat=38.0000114440918, truelat1=30.0, truelat2=60.0, pole_lat=90.0, pole_lon=0.0)
orientation : (162.0, 246.0) to (168.0, 8.0)
missing_value : 9.969209968386869e+36
_FillValue : 9.969209968386869e+36
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all: "ValueError: unable to infer dtype on variable 'xy_loc'; xarray cannot serialize arbitrary Python objects".

The `xy_loc` coordinate contains an array of type `object`, meaning they're not numpy arrays of uniform dtype, e.g. `float64`, `int32`, etc. Instead, the numpy array holds pointers to python objects. The first element is something called `CoordPair(x=162.0, y=246.0, lat=...`. I'm not sure what this is, and it seems neither is xarray.

When xarray writes to netCDF, it [serializes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) the data, meaning it converts it from a python in-memory data structure (e.g. `DataArray`, `Coordinate`, etc) to a file with a specific encoding. The netCDF file specification doesn't have a built-in way to handle arbitrary python objects - it must have a protocol for encoding the data. numpy float64s get converted to netCDF `long`, dask.arrays get converted to netCDF chunks, etc.

If you have an object that is not something that xarray knows what to do with, you must do some preprocessing to prepare the data for storage. For example, can you change your `xy_loc` dim into a positional index, and add additional coordinates which give the information contained in the xy_loc object:

```py
# add non-dimensional coordinates for each attribute of each CoordPair
da.coords['x'] = ('xy_loc', ), [c.x for c in xy_loc.values]
da.coords['y'] = ('xy_loc', ), [c.y for c in xy_loc.values]
da.coords['lat'] = ('xy_loc', ), [c.lat for c in xy_loc.values]
da.coords['lon'] = ('xy_loc', ), [c.lon for c in xy_loc.values]

# finally, replace the coord xy_loc itself with a positional index
da.corods['xy_loc'] = np.arange(len(da.xy_loc))
```

Now, you should be able to save the object as netCDF